# Applying Agile methodology - Testing /QA in Infrastructure Projects

Tags: test-management, agile-testing, agile

What advice do you have for promoting Agile methodology in delivering Infrastructure projects.
Can this be done to good advantage for Quality assurance purposes or are infrastructure projects too specialised to allow this to be done successfully. What have you tried and found to be the case?

Comment: When you say "infrastructure", do you mean something without a user interface, or something internal to the company, or something else?

Comment: @user246 I mean principally the platforms including databases, server hosts and network connectivity to support  corporate business processing and activities. Pernilla O

Answer (score 3):

I would have a look at Kanban, great article here:

http://agilesysadmin.net/kanban_sysadmin

I have worked with a devops team run by Stephen Nelson-Smith (I was running the test team and we had lots of things we wanted the ops team to do for us, ranging from setting up test infrastructure to deploying applications on servers, etc) and I have to say that it was one of the best devops teams I've ever had the pleasure to work with.  They were responsive to our needs, happy to reprioritise work and we could always get a good view of what was going on by looking at their kanban board.

Of course the fact that everybody on the team was a highly skilled individual helped, but having highly skilled individuals who are crippled with a workflow that makes them unresponsive and reactionary rather than proactive is probably more rustrating than having people who don't know what they are doing (You can excuse the idiots, because you know they don't know any better...).